# How to make use of store parameter openerp?

Tags: python, parameters, odoo, store

I like to know the property of **Store Parameter** in **OpenERP**.

```
syntax : store = { 'object_name': ( function_name, ['field_name1', 'field_name2'], priority) }
```

1. Is it possible to use store parameter for all types of fields, example (simple, relation, functional)?
2. What is the purpose of store parameter ?

After reading the Technical document, it's not clear for me. Please explain.

And once again thank for everyone for good support for newbies.

Comment: Hi AnomA , thanks for your immediate reply .But still its not clear for me . Can you please explain this sample code ....

Comment: Can you please explain this sample code ....addons/purchase/purchase.py                                          class purchase_order(osv.osv):                                             _columns = {         'minimum_planned_date':fields.function(_minimum_planned_date, fnct_inv=_set_minimum_planned_date, string='Expected Date', type='date', select=True, help="This is computed as the minimum scheduled date of all purchase order lines' products.",
            store = {
                'purchase.order.line': (_get_order, ['date_planned'], 10),
            }
        ), }

Answer (score -1):

I dont know much about it. store mainly used in functional fields store data.
`'store'=True` will store the value of the field in database. Once stored then the functional fields function will not be executed again.

But if the value of 'store' is a dictionary then (key of the dictionary will be a model name and value will a tuple with list of ids, list of field name and priority--i dont know ) any change/update in the model specified as the key of the dictionary AND any change/ update in the ids specified in the tuple AND any change / update is in the field names specified in the list then the function of the functional field will be loaded again and new data will be saved in functional field

Reference:[OpenERP fields.function() explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185195/openerp-fields-function-explanation/16206895#16206895)