# Display fields.function on tree view odoo

Tags: python, treeview, odoo

I need to display values from one2many field in tree view, so I decided to create functional field and declared it on my xml tree view:

```
def get_product_brands(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context):
    res={}
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=None).application_data_product_template_ids:
        brands = record.brand.name or ''
    print brands
    res[record.id] = brands
    return res
```

and my field declaration:

```
'brands' : fields.function(get_product_brands, method=True, string="Product brands", type='char', store=True)
```

xml sample code:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="product_tree_inherit">
    <field name="name">product.tree.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_tree_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
         <xpath expr="//field[@name='categ_id']" position="after"> 
             <field name="brands"/>
         </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

In my console, I can see correct records printed but I does not display anything in my tree view.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

remove the store attribute from function field

Comment: Your answer is right...try to explain more to the OP why `store=True` doesn't work. so it will be useful to others that come across your answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185195/openerp-fields-function-explanation/16206895#16206895

Answer (score 0):

It's only because wrong indentation in code. Try following,

```
def get_product_brands(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context):
    res={}
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=None).application_data_product_template_ids:
        brands = record.brand.name or ''
        print brands
        res[record.id] = brands
    return res
```

You have placed `res[record.id]` out side the loop, that's it.

Comment: File "/home/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 5219, in ensure_one
    raise except_orm("ValueError", "Expected singleton: %s" % self)
except_orm: ('ValueError', 'Expected singleton: product.template(8, 4, 5, 9, 2, 3, 7)')

Comment: If I use this function, I get this error, do you know why it might be?